# Is it possible to "replicate" databases with only cpanel/phpmyadmin access?

Tags: mysql

I need to auto sync two databases in different servers (in "real" time), but replicate need to change Mysql config and I only have access to cpanel/phpmyadmin and my FTP "root" account of this cpanel account.

Thanks!

Comment: In short .. If you don't have server level-access it's not possible in the sense of what you are asking -- If you are asking for "real time" replication.  Of course manual replication can be done by exporting / importing, but I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: i assume you are on a shared web hosting account (because of cpanel usage).. replication requires full MySQL control most likely shared webhoster will not allow so you need to get a two dedicated or vps servers where your run your own MySQL servers.